# SetPadding of one single elemet in a layout whith many childrens

Tags: javafx

There is a way to set a Padding of one single element in a VBox having other childrens?

```java
this.layout_p = new VBox();
this.txta_p = new TextArea();
this.m_p = new Button("m");
this.o_p = new Button("o");
this.c_p = new Button("c");
this.oa_p = new Button("oa");
this.np_p = new Button("np'");

layout_p.getChildren().addAll(txta_p, m_p, 
o_p, c_p, oa_p, np_p);
layout_p.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
```

I would like to have the button: np_p with a top padding of 50 from others buttons.
So having a separation between oa_p and np_p.

(Without using another VBox for that button and so, setPadding(...))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a padding for a single node does not make sense. Padding is the room between the bounds of a node and it's content, see also the [CSS Box Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Box_model).

You're actually trying to add a margin here, i.e. some space around the node. This can be done using [`VBox.setMargin`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/VBox.html#setMargin(javafx.scene.Node,javafx.geometry.Insets)).

```
VBox.setMargin(np_p, new Insets(50, 0, 0, 0));
```